# Update from UltraGrid where a condition is true

Tags: sql, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a form in a project with 2 `UltraGrids` on it. One displays contract information, the other contains module information.

In the contracts grid, there may be 3 rows, for example, each with a unique contract ID. When a row is clicked on, it populates the modules grid with the modules that are assigned under that contract.

What I need to do, is update the modules where the contactID in the database, matches the ID in the selected contract row.

The code I have so far is

```
For Each ugr As UltraGridRow In ugModules.Rows
   For Each ur As UltraGridRow In ugContracts.Rows

     mID = ugr.Cells("ModuleID").Text
     mName = ugr.Cells("ModuleName").Text
     numUsers = ugr.Cells("NumberUsers").Text

     sql = "UPDATE dbo.tblModules SET ModuleName = ?, NumberUsers = ? WHERE ContractID = ? AND ModuleID = ?"
     cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mName
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@numusers", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = numUsers
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@conID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ur.Cells("ContractID").Value
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@mid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mID

       If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 0 Then
          sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblModules(ModuleID, ModuleName, NumberUsers, ContractID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)"
          cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@mid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mID
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mName
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@numusers", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = numUsers
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@conID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ur.Cells("ContractID").Value

          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
       End If
    Next
Next
```

The problem with this code, is that it is trying to update every module from every contract associated to the current customer, which is causing clashes in the ID fields.

Is there a way to modify this code so that it will only update records that have the contractID which is being edited, rather than all of the contract ID's that are displayed in the contacts table?

(Apologies, this is a little hard to explain, happy to clarify anything if it's casing confusion)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you should get rid of the outer loop and use the ActiveRow property

```vb
Dim ctrRow = ugContracts.ActiveRow
if ctrRow IsNot Nothing Then

   ' Extract the contractid from the ugContracts active row and use it
   Dim contractID = ctrRow.Cells("ContractID").Value

   For Each ugr As UltraGridRow In ugModules.Rows
     mID = ugr .Cells("ModuleID").Text
     mName = ugr .Cells("ModuleName").Text
     numUsers = ugr .Cells("NumberUsers").Text
     sql = "UPDATE dbo.tblModules SET 
                   ModuleName = ?, 
                   NumberUsers = ? 
            WHERE ContractID = ? AND ModuleID = ?"
     cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = mName
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@numusers", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = numUsers
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@conID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = contractID
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@mid", OleDbType.Integer).Value = mID

     ....
     .... also the insert part can use the contractID variable
     ....

   Next
End If
```

**EDIT**
if your modules grid contains all the modules and you use the filter functionality of the UltraGrid (by code is AllowRowFiltering, FilterConditions etc...) then you can retrieve only the rows that are included in the current filter (and thus visible on the grid) using this method

```
For Each ur As UltraGridRow In ugModules.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows()
   .....
Next
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I've already retrieved the contractID, that isn't an issue. It's the modules grid that I'm having the issue with, since it filters which rows it displays, based on the contact selected (different modules to different rows). Therefore, I need to only update the visible rows in the ultragrid, if this is possible?

Comment: How do you filter the modules grid? I suppose that when you select a contract the module grid is filled only with modules belonging to that contract. Or do you fill the grid will all existant modules and then use the Filter functionality of the grid?

Comment: The first one, the grid is filled with the modules in that contract

Comment: I am sorry but then I don't understand the problem. If your ugModules grid contains only the modules of a single contract then what is the problem with the code presented above? You get the contractID from the ActiveRow of the ugContracts, then every module should be updated with the current data displayed by the grid. (also remember that you can use the same OleDbDataAdapter used to fill the DataSource of the grid to execute the Update)

Comment: It's using the old values in the update, so the new values are not getting entered into the DB

Comment: Are you sure? There is no reason that this can be, unless you're setting the `DataSource` again at some point within the save function